# Email verification using php

Tags: php, email-verification

I am new here, and I am continuing previous developer website for the client.
This web will sent an verification email for user after the user sign up for member in the web.
The email is send to the user but my problem now is that the verification doesn't work. When the user click on the verification link, it's does link to the verification.php but show a blank page.
I don't know where is the problem.
This is the account_verification.php file:

```
session_start();  
require_once 'cms/configuration.php';

$username = $_GET['e_username'];
$key = $_GET['key'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$memberID = $row['id'];

if ($key == md5($username.$row['id']))
{
    $sql = "UPDATE member SET verified = '1' WHERE id = '{$row['id']}'";    
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo '  <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Your account is activated."); 
            window.location = "homepage.php"; 
            </script>';
}
?>
```

And this is the membersignup.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'cms/configuration.php';
include "includes/phpmailer.php";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $_POST[$key] = $value;
}


$e_username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = $_POST['password'];
$ic_no = $_POST['ic_no'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$comp_name = $_POST['comp_name'];
$comp_address = $_POST['comp_address'];
$comp_contact = $_POST['comp_contact'];
$comp_fax = $_POST['comp_fax'];
$comp_email = $_POST['comp_email'];
$about_us = $_POST['about_us'];
$datetime = $_POST['datetime'];

;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM member WHERE username='$e_username'");
$num_records = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_records !=0){
    echo "Please use different username.";
    exit();
}


$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO member (username, password, ic_no,email, birthday, contact, address, company_name, company_address, company_contact, company_fax, company_email, about_us, register_date)
                VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',NOW())",


        mysql_real_escape_string($e_username),
        md5($password),
        mysql_real_escape_string($ic_no),
        mysql_real_escape_string($email),
        mysql_real_escape_string($dob),
        mysql_real_escape_string($contact),
        mysql_real_escape_string($address),
        mysql_real_escape_string($comp_name),
        mysql_real_escape_string($comp_address),
        mysql_real_escape_string($comp_contact),
        mysql_real_escape_string($comp_fax),
        mysql_real_escape_string($comp_email),
        mysql_real_escape_string($about_us),
        mysql_real_escape_string($datetime)
);
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$insertID = mysql_insert_id();
$key = md5($_POST['username'].$insertID);
$link = "http://___/account_verification.php?username={$_POST['username']}&key=$key";
$body = "<div>
            <p style='padding:10px;'>
            Hello {$_POST['username']}!
            </p>
            <p style='padding:10px;'>
            Thank you for creating an account at ___.
            </p>
            <p style='padding:10px;'>
            Please keep this e-mail for your records. Your account information is as follows:<br/>
            Username : $e_username <br/>
            Password : {$_POST['password']}
            </p>
            <p style='padding:10px;'>
            Verify your account to complete your registration by clicking the link:<br/>
            <a href='$link' target='_blank'>$link</a>
            </p>
            <p style='padding:10px;'>&nbsp;</p>
            <p style='padding:10px;'>
            Thanks,<br/>Admin
            </p>
        </div>";
$subject = "Member Registration and Verification";
if ($result)
{
    $sendMailResult = sendPHPMail('noreply@___.com', '___', $_POST['email'], $subject, $body);
    if($sendMailResult == TRUE)
        echo 1;
    else
        echo "There's problem sending validation mail to your email. Please try again later.";
}
else
{
    echo "There's problem saving your registration details to our database. Please try again later.";   
}

?>
```

Can anyone help me to find what is the problem here?

Comment: Its easy to debug. Is control going inside that `if` statement in your verification file? echo some debugging stuff there to see

Comment: `echo "DEBUG: key == $key, md5 == ".md5($username.$row['id']);` right before the if

Comment: erm410; I already try that but it still show a blank page.

Comment: Ok then check if your connection to database is successful? because I don't see anywhere a connection, maybe its in the included configuration file. Need to check the return values. Maybe it stops at that

Comment: `if (!$result) { echo mysql_error(); exit(); }` will let you know if the queries work

Comment: Okay. Now when I put this 
echo "DEBUG: key == $key, md5 == ".md5($username.$row['id']);
before the if statement, it will show in the page but if I put it in the if statement, then it doesn't show.

Comment: DEBUG: key == 4b377d23309d4ed39c9da5791417aeff, md5 == d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
This is what the page show.

Comment: Your select statement is probably failing then as hanky suggested. Figure out why and your page will work as expected

Comment: I already do some changes as suggested by Becs Carter and it solve the problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for a user that matches `$username = $_GET['e_username'];` when you are actually only sending in the url  `username`

So, your account_verification.php should be

```
session_start();  
require_once 'cms/configuration.php';

$username = $_GET['username'];
$key = $_GET['key'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '$username'";
etc ...
```

And your link to this script should be as follows: (note: your username variable is changed to $_POST['e_username']

```
$link = "http://___/account_verification.php?username={$_POST['e_username']}&key=$key";
```

Comment: Is there any other alternative? It's seem like it 's not working after I change those code to the one that you suggested...